# Plugins in symlinked directories?

Tags: plugin-development, customization

When I develop plugins I test them on multiple versions of WordPress by symlinking my plugin directory in the different `wp-content` directories. This is great since I only have to edit the files once, but it breaks an important construct to generate references to resources in my plugin: `__FILE__` refers to the physical plugin location, not the one in `wp-content`. How should I solve this?

My directory structure looks like this:

- `/path/to/wordpress/development/dir/`

  - `plugin-development/`

    - `monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/`

      - `monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer.php`
      - `js/`

        - `monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer.js`
  - `versions/`

    - `3.1/`

      - `wp-content/`

        - `plugins/`

          - `monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer` as a symlink to the above plugin
    - `3.1-multi-dir/`

      - `wp-content/`

        - `plugins/`

          - `monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer` as a symlink to the above plugin
    - `3.1-multi-domain/`

      - `wp-content/`

        - `plugins/`

          - `monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer` as a symlink to the above plugin

If I want to enqueue the Javascript file, I should use `plugins_url( 'monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer.js', [base file] )`, but using `__FILE__` here will not work, because the actual file path will be `/path/to/wordpress/development/dir/plugin-development/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer.php`, not `/path/to/wordpress/development/dir/versions/*/wp-content/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer.php`, so WordPress cannot strip the first part out and generate a URL relative to the WordPress installation.

Answer (score 7):

The problem can partially be addressed with a must-use plugin hooking into the `plugins_url` filter.

It won't handle all other cases where `plugin_basename()` is used, such as `register_activation_hook()` and co.

More info: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16953

Comment: I believe using `WP_PLUGIN_URL` is not recommended because administrators should be allowed to change the name of this specific plugin's directory, but is there also another reason to avoid it? And indeed, your ticket would be a simple solution.

Comment: On the contrary. WP_PLUGIN_URL only contains the URL that points directly to the 'plugins' dir. See updated answer.

Comment: @scribu: But what if my plugins lives in `/external/folder/banana-plugin/` but the admin links to that directory as `/httpd-root/wp-content/plugins/apple-plugin/`? Then it will try to go to `/wp-content/plugins/banana-plugin/`, no? And I believe the admin should be free to choose the individual plugin directory names?

Comment: I won't argue with you about that anymore, because I found the solution: the 'plugins_url' filter. Updated answer again.

Comment: FWIW this solution can be error prone and depends on plugin devs only using plugins_url() after all plugins have loaded, otherwise you can't register a filter before the function is called. the Akismet plugin and many others have that problem.

Comment: Refreshed the answer.

Comment: Ok, use the filter...but how?  what would the function be to correct the url?

Answer (score 3):

I currently use a trick to get the WordPress-relative file location: `wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins()` returns the file paths, and [`wp_settings.php` loops over them and includes the files](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-settings.php#L188). So the global `$plugin` variable will refer to your current plugin (of course only when the plugin is loaded, so I save it in a prefixed global variable):

```
$monkeyman_Rewrite_Analyzer_file = $plugin;
```

Because plugins can also be loaded as must-use or network plugins and [these loops use other variable names](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-settings.php#L152), the complete code looks like this:

```
$monkeyman_Rewrite_Analyzer_file = __FILE__;
if ( isset( $mu_plugin ) ) {
    $monkeyman_Rewrite_Analyzer_file = $mu_plugin;
}
if ( isset( $network_plugin ) ) {
    $monkeyman_Rewrite_Analyzer_file = $network_plugin;
}
if ( isset( $plugin ) ) {
    $monkeyman_Rewrite_Analyzer_file = $plugin;
}
```

The fallback is still `__FILE__`, so if someone changes the loop variable name in the future my code should still work for 99% of all installations, only my development setup will fail and I can release a new version with ease.

Comment: Great solution @Jan. I implemented something similar by calling the functions and looping because I forgot those variables were accessible as `global`. Thanks to your post here I realized I could make it much simpler.  BTW, I'm also testing for `false === strpos( __FILE__, WP_CONTENT_DIR )` before running your if statements because I'm assuming if the plugin is in the `WP_CONTENT_DIR` it's not symlinked; I'm hoping that's valid logic.

Answer (score 0):

A comment in [bug 46260](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46260) suggests to use `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]` instead of `__FILE__`. Does this work?

Comment: No, this does not change in included files. So if `index.php` includes `library.php`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` in `library.php` will still be `index.php`. But thanks for the reference to the bug, I'll follow it closely!

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]` works if you use it right.  You just have to use it to set a base path, and then include your files using a path relative to that base path.

Something like:

```
$plugin_dir = dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
$myFile = $plugin_dir."/includes/js/myJavascriptFile.js";
```

Note, this is more useful when you don't have access to wp-blog-header.php yet (i.e. in processing an ajax-based form request)