# Symbolic Links on dev box with plugins and stylesheets

Tags: plugin-development, urls, wp-config, paths

I'm using mac os x 10.6 with xampp.

`http://wp3.1/` is the url to where I have WordPress installed.

The physical path is `/Users/myUserName/Sites/wp3.1/`

I do not install plugins or themes in the "natural" way. I have created a directory named "git" which is located in `/Users/myUserName/git/`. This is where all my git repositories live. When I want to install a plugin, I just create a symbolic link in `/Users/myUserName/Sites/wp3.1/wp-content/plugins/`. This works great for simple plugins, but if the plugin enqueue's a style sheet or script, the url displays as:

`http://wp3.1/wp-content/plugins/Users/myUserName/git/options-framework-plugin/css/colorpicker.css?ver=3.1.1`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Symbolic links are … [risky](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15202/plugins-in-symlinked-directories) in WordPress. It is easier to use a separate domain for plugins per wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', '/local/path/to/plugin/directory' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://plugins.dev');
```

See [Strategy On Building Plugin Using Eclipse](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14495/73) as an example for IDE configuration with such a setup.

Comment: Interesting ... Thanks! Going to give this a try right away.

Comment: This worked liked a charm. Thanks so much! It took me a while to get my vhosts set up, but now everythings working perfectly. Mad Props!!!

Comment: @toscho: Won't using a separate domain for your plugins create issues with cross-domain security in browsers? WP Cookies that are not transferred when you access something in `http://plugins.dev/myplugin/myaction.php'?

Comment: @Jan Fabry Plugins which rely on cookies for their file path are broken by definition. One plus of a separate domain is the reduced HTTP overhead.

Comment: @Jan Fabry I'm using this method for development only. IMO, plugins coded to access their files are doing it wrong. Actions such as this should be handled by admin-ajax.php.

Comment: Interesting concept. I use symlinks without any issue under XAMPP on Windows 7 ... but I might try this method just to be safe.

Comment: +1 This is possible for Plugins as well as MU-Plugins, but sadly not for Dropins, which have to stay in your `~/wp-content` dir...

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the plugin URL is correct except for the real path stuck in the middle. We can filter the function responsible for generating plugin URLs and remove this.

The following code should be installed as a [Must Use Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins):

```
add_filter( 'plugins_url', function( $url ) {
    return str_replace( '/Users/myUserName/git/', '', $url );
});
```