# Where are plugins located

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, localhost

I typically download and install plugins via FTP, but I have installed a few from the web interface.  I am trying to move WP from remote to local and I am getting a blank wp-admin screen.  I think its one of my plugins causing the problem.  I have renamed wp-content/plugins to wp-content/_plugins to disable all the plugins in that folder.  But I have plugins installed that do not appear in the plugins folder which I believe are causing this blank wp-admin screen.  Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: I have searched for this issue and many have indicated this happens from blank spaces at the top and bottom of functions.php.  That is not the case here.

Comment: Why don't you try to do the exact same thing for themes? Also enable debug mode in `wp-config.php` you should get a clearer error message.

Answer (score 10):

The two directories, where plugins can be located in line with normal mechanics are:

- `wp-content/plugins`
- `wp-content/mu-plugins`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer of @toscho - [Symbolic Links on dev box with plugins and stylesheets](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15483/symbolic-links-on-dev-box-with-plugins-and-stylesheets)