# Multi-Site / Single Site Decisions

Tags: multisite

New to wordpress here and I've seen some conflicting recommendations on whether or not my particular site design would benefit from it or not.

Instead of guessing and not knowing for certain I thought I would check here.

I'm planning on having a site with a single 'branding' but multiple contributors - blog writers, podcasts, video sections, etc. - each with a unique audience but a shared branding (under the domain name, all getting periodic exposure on the sites main page)

The sites would be things like blogname.domain.com, blogname2.domain.com, podcast1.domain.com and so forth. If one were to be popular enough I would want to separate the branding some and make it something like blogname2.com instead of blogname2.domain.com

My question is this - if there are various content producers with slightly different templates but a 'shared' userbase (ie. userA can register/subscribe to blogname.domain.com but will now be able to comment/participate on any other blog/podcast/whatever on the site) do I want to use a single-site or multi-site configuration?

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: If separate sites need to be share users, you need multisite.

Comment: The sites are all on the same primary domain and separated only by 'subdomain' designations - is that important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best (and perhaps only) way to get wordpress working in a situation like the one described above (being set up on separate subdomains with the same userbase, etc) is by using the multi-site installation.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't mention if you WANTED users to be communal and to be able to cross post. If you do want that, then multisite is what you're after. If you don't, then go by way of single site.

You can still run multiple single site blogs off a single install by modifying the config file to include the table names and prefixes for each blog.

check out: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51326/37314

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I did want multisite for the reason you mentioned but I have been getting in to quite a bit more WordPress stuff lately and appreciate this info!