# Symbolic Links for themes - linking one theme to many wordpress installs

Tags: themes

This discussion relateds to plugins: [Symbolic Links on dev box with plugins and stylesheets](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15483/symbolic-links-on-dev-box-with-plugins-and-stylesheets)

I was wondering if the same problem exists for symlinking a theme to many different wordpress installs.

**Example structure:**

> domain/footheme/ <- theme resides here

**The following domains symlinks created here:**

> domain/myfoo.com/wp-content/theme/(footheme)
>
> domain/myfoo2.com/wp-content/theme/(footheme)
>
> domain/myfoo3.com/wp-content/theme/(footheme)

**Example Symlink Creation**

`ln -s domain/footheme domain/myfoo.com/wp-content/theme/footheme`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to project constraints i ended up just creating custom themes for both.

If i was to approach this now i would probably manage it by creating a git repository and maintaining multiple git submodules