# Is it safe to pass directory path to plugins_url()?

Tags: plugins-url

[`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) function accepts plugin slug or file path to build URL for.

I have following directory structure:

```
/wp-content/mu-plugins/someplugin/css/file.css
/wp-content/mu-plugins/someplugin/includes/file.php
```

I need to build URL to `file.css` in `file.php`. I can't pass `__FILE__` because that will be one level too deep.

```
plugins_url('css/file.css', __FILE__ )
```

I can pass `__DIR__` to get correct level and it seems to work, but it's not documented as allowed and I am not sure there isn't something to bite me later with this.

```
plugins_url('css/file.css', __DIR__ )
```

So, is this adequate? Any better way to build URL for these conditions?

Comment: I would [save the main plugin file in a global variable](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15202/plugins-in-symlinked-directories/15204#15204) and use that everywhere, certainly in included files. So `$wpse15731_file` would end with `mu-plugins/someplugin/someplugin.php`, and it doesn't matter that my code is in `includes/file.php` or somewhere else.

Comment: @Jan Fabry main stuff not up to me, I just merge new chunk into larger project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__DIR__` is rather new and not always supported. Use `dirname( __FILE__ )`.

`plugins_url()` is using …

```
$folder = dirname(plugin_basename($plugin));
```

… so yes, it is safe.

Just use `plugins_url( 'subfolder/file.css', dirname( __FILE__ ) )`

Comment: Probably, but the main question - is it safe to pass **directory** path instead of **file** path at all to this one?

Comment: Oops, I completed my answer.

Comment: @toscho that just moves question level deeper - [`plugin_basename()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_basename) is supposed to take file path as well.

Comment: @Rarst A directory is just a special file. Looking at the code for `plugin_basename()` I don’t see anything that may break if you pass a directory.

Comment: Ok, if you say so. :) I am just cautious because I develop on different platform than I deploy to. Moving code from Windows to Linux at times ends up with epic... issues.

Comment: As long as the second parameter you pass to `plugins_url` ends with `yourplugin-dir/somethingelse[/]`, `dirname()` can chop off the `/somethingelse` part, and `plugins_url` gets `yourplugin-dir` as it needs. So it does not matter whether `somethingelse` is a file or a dir, it doesn't need to exist.